# What is exactly mean by 'DisallowConcurrentExecution' in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have a Quartz.net Job with the following definition.

```
    [PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
    [DisallowConcurrentExecution]
    public class AdItemsJob : IJob, IInterruptableJob
    {

        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        { 
         // Job execution logic,

        }
   }
```

As I have decorated the Job with `DisallowConcurrentExecution` attribute.
What I know about this attribute, we can't run multiple instances of same job at the same time. What is meant by multiple instances here.?
Does the two jobs of `AddItemsJob`  with different key are called same instances or different instances.?
Does two jobs with different key can execute at the same time.?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A job *instance* is a job with unique key. So having a job of *type* AddItemsJob can have two instances with keys AddItemsJob.Admin and AddItemsJobs.Legacy. 
The concurrency protection comes per job key - the aforementioned two jobs could run simultaneously if they were defined with overlapping triggers.
Having a single job defined behind single key would not run simultaneously even if there were multiple triggers having overlapping schedules associated with it.

Comment: Thanks Marko! Your essay make sense.