# Quartz.NET 2.6.1: Multiple Triggers for same Job trigger at same time, but need only one trigger to occur

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I have **Jobs** with multiple **Triggers**. In some cases, the Triggers will overlap. When Quartz.NET determines the overlapping Triggers need to be triggered, the `IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)` method is executed for each Trigger.

Is there a way to prevent this overlap?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is exactly mean by 'DisallowConcurrentExecution' in Quartz.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390698/what-is-exactly-mean-by-disallowconcurrentexecution-in-quartz-net)

Comment: Just use `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` attribute in the job implementation

Comment: @Najera Thanks for the response. I have tried this, but all this does is prevent the triggered instances of the job running simultaneously. If I have three triggers that all trigger at the same time, the attribute you mentioned forces the job to run three times sequentially.

Comment: That is a different need, how often this needs to run once?

Comment: It will always need to run once; regardless of how many triggers fire for that job.

Comment: Triggers are fired exactly same time?

Comment: They are, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I would give it a chance:

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class Job : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        bool wasExecutedAt = WasExecutedAt(context.ScheduledFireTimeUtc);
    }

    private bool WasExecutedAt(DateTimeOffset? fireTime)
    {
         // Check and maintain the state
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to have worked. Thanks Najera! For others who see this post, I persisted in the "context.JobDetail.JobDataMap" object, and added the [PersistJobDataAfterExecution] attribute against the class.

Comment: In theory, @Najera, your code is fine. Unfortunately, there is a bug in Quartz.NET (appears to be going on since at least 2016) whereby the "ScheduledFireTimeUtc" is actually set to the "FireTimeUtc".

Do you happen to know if there is a way to get the proper value for the schedule fire time, at the time it actually triggered?

The bug reported on github for this is: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/605

Comment: I refactored to create a base class implementing IJob, and I put the DisallowConcurrentExecution and PersistJobDataAfterExecution attributes onto the base class. I had to move the attributes and put them against all of my derived classes to make it all start working again. This is a shame, as the code in my base class (based on @Najera example) is useless without those attributes.