# Using @DisallowConcurrentExecution in Quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am sorry if this question is too naive,
I am expecting the jobs to be scheduled so that it executes **one by one, and not parallely.It is executed only once.**

From docs, @DisallowConcurrentExecution is

- An annotation that marks a {@link Job} class as one that must not have multiple instances executed concurrently (where instance is based-upon a {@link JobDetail} definition - or in other words based upon a {@link JobKey}).

But when I schedule a job with same JobKey, I am getting 
`Failed to schedule a job org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException`

If I generate a different JobKey, it is not heeding to `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` and the job is getting executed in parallel(as mentioned in docs).

Please suggest how can I achieve this, any pointers would really help!

PS: I do not know the jobs that would be scheduled. So, I need some method to dynamically link up the jobs,if the job is already running.

Comment: [what-is-exactly-mean-by-disallowconcurrentexecution-in-quartz-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390698/what-is-exactly-mean-by-disallowconcurrentexecution-in-quartz-net?rq=3)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Same `JobKey` = same job.
Different `JobKey` = different job.

Quartz won't let you use the same `JobKey` more than once because that'd be two jobs with the same key. Like having two users with the same ID.

What you need to do is schedule different `JobTrigger`s for the same `JobKey`.

`@DisallowConcurrentExecution` avoids overlapping executions of the *same* job. If you use a different `JobKey`, it's not the same job anymore, so the annotation doesn't have any effect. But for a given `JobKey` with several `JobTrigger`s, `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` will keep the triggers from launching a new execution of the job, if the previous one hasn't finished yet.

I suggest having a look at [Quartz's documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-02.html) to get a deeper understanding of the above concepts.