# How can I implement cron jobs/scheduled jobs in a distributed environment without centralized solution like Quartz Clustering?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I would like to implement cron jobs/scheduled jobs along side with my Web services in a single Spring artifact. Since the artifact is deployed in a distributed environment, the scheduled jobs may consume the same data/job multiple times, which is I tried to avoid.

The common solution seems to be using a centralized cluster like Quartz Clustering, which involves an additional database to store the status of the jobs. But I do not want to introduce too much complexity in my system architecture for now, is there any other better solution?

Comment: Maybe an shared cache.

Comment: Maybe the following link can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492285/scheduler-on-multiple-server-instances/62495825#62495825

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to elect one server for each job to be executed.

Is it acceptable that it's the same server for every job?

And what needs to happen if that one server is inactive? How do you tell if it's inactive?

If you have a shared cache (e.g. Hazelcast) or a shared database (SQL or NoSQL), you can create a lock table and do something clever to conditionally insert a record with each server's ip if none exists, and see who wins. You can use the same table as a heart beat by adding a timestamp field and updating it every X seconds from the elected master. If the other servers keep reading it, they can detect that the master is dead after X+Y seconds, and another can take over.

There's also Zookeeper, if you want to add that to your stack. The Curator framework has a recipe for LeaderElection: https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/leader-election.html

In the past I also saw JGroups being used: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/06/jgroups-leader-election-without-additional-infrastructure.html
But that relies on IP broadcast or multicast, so that might not work in your network topology.