# Quartz job completed but the thread remains blocked

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp, quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz Job like this

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MyJob{

     public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
         //connect to a FTP server, monitor directory for new files and download
         //Using FTPClient of commons-net-3.5.jar 
     }
```

The job is triggered with

```
JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(MyJob.class)
    .withIdentity(jobName, DEFAULT_GROUP)
    .usingJobData(new JobDataMap(jobProperties))
    .build();   

//trigger every minute                  
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity(jobName, DEFAULT_GROUP)
    .startNow()
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule(cronExpression))
    .build();

scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);
```

The job is triggered every minute. It works well for about 1 week (10000 Executions) **and inexplicably not relaunches**. There are no errors in the log and see that it has completed the previous execution. The other processes are firing correctly.

Upgrading libraries to `quartz-2.2.3` and `commons-net-3.5` (looking for a possible bug in the FTP library) I managed to last 3 weeks

I have a `Job` to monitor `Scheduler` that says trigger state is `BLOCKED`. The `Thread` of the blocked process is not reused by application server

```
 TriggerState triggerState = scheduler.getTriggerState(triggerKey);
```

I have not found documentation on this type of problem with Quartz, so my suspicion is a bug in the FTP library that interferes with the thread started by quartz for example with the usage of `@PersistJobDataAfterExecution`

**I wonder if it's a known issue or could be a bug** so I could apply a solution or a workaround ( killing the quartz job [how to stop/interrupt quartz scheduler job manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467320/how-to-stop-interrupt-quartz-scheduler-job-manually))

Comment: It fails always in the same execution or time? Which pattern has the job assigned?

Comment: The failure time varies between 3 days and 3 weeks (4300 - 30000 executions), but occasionally failed in 24h. Usually fails after an empty execution: FTP connect, no files, disconnect. The cron expression is : `0 0/1 * * * ?`

Comment: maybe this empty execution throws any unhandled exception or error that may affect cron? pattern and job seem to be created in the right way...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JordiCastilla. In the last change, I added a log line as the final step of the execution method surrounded with a big `try/catch/finally` to ensure there is no a uncatched exception. Also I have reviewed  application server logs looking for lost exceptions, but no luck. I think if it was an exception, the process will fail, but does not maintain the thread blocked (the Java `thread` is not used anymore) . Maybe last action of quartz ( `PersistJobDataAfterExecution`) is being blocked for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

After months with occasional drops of service and suspect that FTP connectivity errors block the service, we have finally implemented a measure that seems to solve the problem

Each process executions do now:

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

//Added connection timeout before connect()
ftp.setDefaultTimeout(getTimeoutInMilliseconds());  

ftp.connect(host, port);

//Added more timeouts to see if thread locks disappear...
ftp.setBufferSize(1024 * 1024);
ftp.setSoTimeout(getTimeoutInMilliseconds());
```

The weird thing is that the process was not blocked previously in `connect()`, the process continued and ended without restarting, but when setting the timeout the problem has not happened again