# Cron job infinite loop

Tags: java, playframework, cron

I have one scenario about cron job, Please see below:

```
import play.jobs.Job;
import play.jobs.On;

@On("1 * * * * ?")
public class TestCron2 extends Job {

    @Override
    public void doJob() {
        try {
            System.out.println("TestCron2 is calling");
            while(true){

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();            
            }

        }
}
```

So this job is meant for running every 1 minute but at very first time it will print the message `TestCron2 is calling` , then it enters the infinite while loop. So it's not able to come out. So next minute onwards it is not calling because the first attempt itself is not completed yet and it won't complete also.

So can someone please clarify me the  following things:

1. Here I am putting infinite `while` loop to point out infinite loop
   situation, but in real scenario my cron job is not completed their
   assigned job due to some unknown reason . So it is not calling next
   interval of time, but it is not happening always.It happened  in a
   month only one or two times.
2. The solution was I need to restart the server and it again started
       working fine.

But Is there any way to restart the cron job without restarting the server?
    I hope I was able to explain this problem properly ,if not please let me know. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: You can use Quartz's InterruptableJob class which will allow you to interrupt a running Job --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159080/how-to-interrupt-or-stop-currently-running-quartz-job