# Stop all jobs executed in the JobService Groovy

Tags: java, grails, groovy

My question is that, when I execute a job from a controller with the following method:

```
def startScheduler(){
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        ///////////////////////////////
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SchedulerJobService.class)
        .withIdentity("SendMailJob","DB")
        .build();
        ///////////////////////////////
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("crontrigger","DB")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronSce))
        .build();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

Calling:

```
class SchedulerJobService implements Job {  
    private static final log = LogFactory.getLog(SchedulerJobService.class) 

    boolean transactional = true

    public void execute (JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) { 
       new SendMailController().sendMail()  
       }
    }
```

In the method `sendMail()` `for` loop is executed, sending a lot of mails, and when I execute `stopScheduler()`:

```
public def stopScheduler(){
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey("crontrigger","DB");
        scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey);
    }
```

The job stops, but the `for` in `new SendMailController().sendMail()` continue his work, until it is finally finished. How to stop it when I execute `stopSceduler()`?

Comment: Is it helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159080/how-to-interrupt-or-stop-currently-running-quartz-job ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: You can het scheduler via `JobExecutionContext`. There's a scheduler's method - `isShutdown()` - it seems that You should use the result of this method in a loop and check if it has changed.

Comment: I'm sorry for the next question, it can be stupid, but how and where I can het scheduler via `JobExecutionContext`? Am I have to implement  more methods in the `class SchedulerJobService implements Job`, because after calling `stopScheduler()` a can not call `public void execute (JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext)`

Comment: Not sure which version You use but `getScheduler()`, see: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html

Comment: The version of the plugin, which I'm using is ":quartz:1.0.2".

Comment: Have you managed to get the scheduler?

Comment: I'm trying to get some more information about this.

Comment: Finally, I have done it with DB.

Comment: Maybe add your answer for future usage?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this with DB (Domain in Grails). In the method `sendMail()` I have:

```
     def sendMail(correoList, nombreList){
                    int index = correoList.size()

                    try{
                        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                            def tcp = TemplateControlPanelText.get(1)
                            if(!tcp.enviando){
                                break;  
                           }
                         .....
                     }
             }catch(Exception e){
        }
   }
```

And in the start:

```
def startScheduler(){
        def t = TemplateControlPanelText.get(1)
        t.enviando = true
        t.save(flush:true)
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
      .....
}
```

And finally when I stop the job I have:

```
public def stopScheduler(){
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();     
        TriggerKey triggerKey = TriggerKey.triggerKey("crontrigger","DB");
        scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey);
        def t = TemplateControlPanelText.get(1)
        t.enviando = false
        t.save(flush:true)
    }
```